# codeigniter captcha not working after server change

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

i have a developpement server in witch the captcha works correctly, but not in production server. i take a look at phpinfo(), and GD is enable on both servers(ubuntu). so i don't understand what is the issue...
here is my code:

```
$vals = array(
                'word' => $this->random_word(6),
                'img_path' => '/var/www/mysite/static/',
                'img_url' => base_url().'static/',
                'font_path'  => '/var/www/mysite/fonts/font.TTF',
                'img_width' => '150',
                'img_height' => '30',
                'expiration' => 7200,
                'word_length' => 6
                );

        $captcha = create_captcha($vals);
```

when i try:

```
var_dump($captcha);
```

the result is:

```
bool(false)
```

Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the img_path is writable by the web server process on the server.

Comment: it is 755 on this folder

Comment: 755 is read/write/execute for the owner, and read/execute for others. So, if the web server process user doesn't own the directory, it cannot write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `image_path` and `font_path` will be relative to that new server like

```
'img_path' => 'new_server_path/mysite/static/',
'img_url' => base_url().'static/',
'font_path'  => 'new_server_path/mysite/fonts/font.TTF',
```

And make sure that those folders will have both `read` and `write` permissions

Comment: the img_path is on chmod 755, like the font_path